# Flutter Grid having items with fixed height and variable width

Tags: list, flutter, grid, masonry

To build a gallery of images, I need an infinite layout, similar to **Grid**, but items have fixed height and variable width, something like the image below, I tried Grid and flutter_staggered_grid_view, but non is suitable. I tried **Wrap** in a **SingleChildScrollView**, but it's not virtual list and renders all items initially, so it's slow:

[image]

Comment: I think Wrap Widget is better on this case. With respect to the images that renders all items, have you tried ```FadeInImage``` i dont know if thats helps

Comment: As I mentioned Wrap tries to measure all items at first, so it's slow.

Comment: @AVEbrahimi have you found any solution to this?

Comment: @LukasHeiligenbrunner No, unfortunately.